# How to Create a Dynamic Property in a class and call it in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I have a Class in that I want to create a dynamic property (or a dynamic variable) to collect Tables list form the database. here is the code

```
include_once($base_dir.'./config/index.php');

class TableList{
        private $con;
        public $Tables_in_sample;

        public function __construct($con){
            $this->conn = $conn;

        }


  public function ListTables(){
    $query ="SHOW TABLES";

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
  }
```

I called it

```
include_once($base_dir.'./config/index.php');
include_once('./tablelist.php');

$dbclass = new DBClass();
$conn = $dbclass->getConnection();

$post = new TableList($conn);

$stmt = $post->ListTables();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();



if($count > 0){

   echo "<html><body><ul>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        extract($row);

        echo  = "<li>".$post->Tables_in_jsonapi."</li>";

    }

    echo "</ul></body></html>";


}
```

Here I got the list of the tables for the DB sample. But I need to get a property dynamically something like this

```
       public  $Tables_in_sample;
```

to

```
      public $Tables_in_.$this->dbname;
```

and collect in

```
echo "<html><body><ul>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        extract($row);

        echo  = "<li>".$post->Tables_in_sample."</li>"; //here 

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any need for this class. It doesn't do anything. Also Why are you trying to extract the row?

Comment: I need that class it has its purpose,  I Just forget this `FETCH_COLUMN`, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Can I ask what do you need that class for?

Comment: @Dharman, This class actually acts as a model.

Comment: Maybe I don't see the whole picture, but it doesn't look like a model to me. Anyway, if you want to keep using this class you should improve it a little. Move `fetchAll` into the method and get rid of `rowCount()`, it should not be used in this context anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic properties, you don't need `extract()`, you don't need the class `TableList`.

```
$result = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo "<html><body><ul>";
foreach ($result as $table) {
    echo '<li>' . $table . '</li>';
}
echo "</ul></body></html>";
```